# Is high availability really not possible with aws emr instance fleets?

Tags: amazon-emr

In the ams emr management guide (https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-emr-management-guide/blob/master/doc_source/emr-instance-fleet.md) I read:

> ... the master instance fleet is only a single instance ...

Does this ultimatly mean, I cannot provision an EMR cluster with instances fleet as high available? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. Although [AWS introduced multiple master nodes](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-emr-announces-support-for-multiple-master-nodes-to-enable-high-availability-for-EMR-applications/) for EMR for high availability in 2019, the same can't be said for fleet instances and the official documentation you mentioned above confirms it.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long pending gap but instance fleets now support HA config.
See more details here:
Amazon EMR on EC2 now supports high-availability instance fleets configuration
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/12/amazon-emr-ec2-high-availability-fleets-configuration/